Unable to Upload App Package Directly, Only 'Package URL' Option Available
I am currently trying to submit my app via the Microsoft Partner Center. However, in the Packages section of my submission, I am only seeing an option to provide a "Package URL" instead of an option to directly upload my app package file (such as .msix, .appx, or .xap).
I would like to submit my package by directly uploading it, but there doesn't appear to be any way to switch from the URL option to the upload option. Could anyone please assist me in enabling the upload option, or let me know if there is a specific setting or submission type I need to adjust?

I tried searching for the problem over internet but in every video and blog they have option for uploading.
